# Yii2 selecting certain fields from related many to many related model

Tags: activerecord, yii2, many-to-many

I manage a junction table to handle `Many to Many` relation. the relation between `items` and its `units` where one item may have one or more unit and one unit may have one or more unit.

In the end, I'm able to get all unit's data for an item like:

```
$item = Items::findOne($id);    
return Json::encode($item->units);
```

However, the JSON object returned has unnecessary fields for the current action. I just need to get unit's `title` and `id`, but it returns all units fields.

I don't know how to adjust this from the relation settings in `Items` model. the following is the relation declaration in Items model:

```
public function getItemUnits()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ItemUnits::className(), ['item_id' => 'id']);
    }

    public function getUnits()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(Units::className(), ['id'=> 'unit_id'])->via('itemUnits');
    }
```

Where `itemUnits` is the junction model, *item_units table*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the more simple solution from the relation declaration. It is in `getUnits` method. I have to add `select` method to it as follows:

```
public function getUnits()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(Units::className(), ['id'=> 'unit_id'])->select(['id','title'])->via('itemUnits');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the related table and modify the join query like so

```
Items::find()
->where(['id'=>$id])
->joinWith(['units'=>function($query){
     $query->select(['id','title']);
}])
->one();
```